# record type in java

Tags: java, types, record

how can i represent a record type in java ??

exemple

```
TYPE Pattern = RECORD

                 Semantique:varchar;
                 type:varchar;
                 chemin:varchar;
               END;
```

Answer (score 5):

Starting with [JDK 14](https://jdk.java.net/14/) ([preview feature](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359)), you can write:

```
record Pattern (String semantique, String type, String chemin);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Record {
  String semantique;
  String type;
  String chemin;
}
```

You may want getters and setters if this is going to be a bean.  Those would look like:

```
public void setType(String type){ this.type=type; }

public String getType() { return type; }
```

Comment: why do you need getters/setters?

Comment: This is a convention that gives other classes access to the internals of your class.  If you use getters and setters, you get better encapsulation because you can later change the behavior of these, or make a property read-only.

Comment: i know that... i just meant in the context of the question.

Comment: In my example, the instance variables are "package" visible, which means that classes in other packages can not access these values.  You could make those public, but that is generally considered bad practice since it exposes internals to other classes.

Comment: I believe that the record type already provides the getters and setters. You should also put a java-14 tag.

Comment: This answer is plain wrong. A record does not allow setters, as **a record by definition is immutable**. Also a record implicitly defines access methods without prefix, for the example of this answer: `String semantique(); String type(); String chemin();`.

Answer (score 0):

You can roughly translate that to Java like this:

```
public class Pattern {
    public String Semantique;
    public String type;
    public String chemin;
}
```

However, this is likely to be substantially different in details than whatever language you're translating from (Pascal?). For example, you can't read and write instances of Java classes directly to disk files.

Comment: You could use an ObjectOutputStream to do so.

Comment: The record's members are `private final` as of JDK 17.

Answer (score 0):

The Java representation (as of JDK 17) would be:

```
record Pattern(String semantique, String type; String chemin) { };
```

A Java record is immutable, i. e. its members cannot be altered plus they are private. That is, their references cannot be altered, their states can unless they are instances of immutable classes like String, LocalDate etc.

By this—without adding any more code—you will get:

a) A canonical constructor

```
public Pattern(String semantique, String type, String chemin) {
  this.semantique = semantique;
  this.type = type;
  this.chemin = chemin;
}
```

b) Reading accessors

```
public String semantique();
public String type();
public String chemin();
```

c) A `boolean equals(Object other)`

This is based on equality of the members—at least it behaves like that for me.

---

In classical Java the above one-liner would look like this:

```
public class Pattern {
  private final String semantique;
  private final String type;
  private final String chemin;

  public Pattern(String semantique; String type; String chemin) {
    this.semantique = semantique;
    this.type = type;
    this.chemin = chemin;
  }

  public String semantique() {
    return semantique;
  }

  public String type() {
    return type;
  }

  public String chemin() {
    return chemin;
  }

  public equals(Object other) {
    if (other == null)
      return false;

    if (false == Pattern.class.isInstance(other)
      return false;

    final var typesafeOther = (Pattern) other;
    return Objects.equals(this.semantique, typeSafeOther.semantique)
      && Objects.equals(this.type, typeSafeOther.type)
      && Objects.equals(this.chemin, typeSafeOther.chemin);
  }
}
```

I am not sure, wether the `.hashCode()` is based on quality of the members, too, but I would expect it to be.

---

You can add:

**validation of input**

```
Pattern {
  Objects.requireNonNull(semantique);
  Objects.requireNonNull(type);
  Objects.requireNonNull(chemin);
}
```

**custom constructors**

This one needs to delegate to another constructor, ultimately calling the canonical constructor at the end of the chain.

```
public Pattern() {
  this("n/A", "n/A", "n/A");
}
```

**custom methods**

This might be silly from your domain's perspective, but it demonstrates the technical possibility.

```
public boolean hasSemantique() {
  return semantique != null && false == semantique.trim().length() > 0;
}
```